# What are the brown gears for?

Tags: super-mario-3d-land

In Level 2-3 of Super Mario 3D Land, by Mario's right foot, there is a block.

If you break that block, there is a brown gear inside of it.

How do I use it? What does it do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to hit it with your Tanooki's suit tail and it will lift the platform it's on.

Comment: So if I don't have a Tanooki suit, I can't use it?

Comment: That's correct, that section of the level is only available if you are using the Tanooki suit.